# What is the best practice for an interface to a library

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, interface, lib

I'm currently implementing a library in C#.
My main class is called `Foo`. It implements the interface `IFoo`.
I'm using the Dependency Injection library from Microsoft to inject this and other dependencies.
My idea was to add the following code to my service provider class:

```
public static IFoo GetFoo()
{
  return ServiceProvider.GetService<IFoo>();
}
```

So the integrator does not have to know how to build an instance of `Foo` and inject the dependencies to it. And the integrator only knows the interface.

I done some research about this topic but I do not find any standards or best practices about this topic.

So my question is are there any any standards or best practices and has my solution any disadvantages?

Thank you!

Comment: There's not enough code to understand fully what you are doing here but it looks like a bad idea. Your library should not know anything about the dependency injection system that's being used to instantiate it. Building the container is the responsibility of the calling app not the library, that's where all the 'wiring up' should happen.

Comment: When I've created libraries built for dependency injection, I've used a `static` Configuration class, that uses extension methods, for the `IServiceCollection` like so: `public static void AddSomeService(this IServiceCollection servicecontainer) { //do your configuration here` then in `program.cs` or `startup.cs` depending on your version of .net, use it like: `builder.Services.AddSomeService();` The Configuration extension method resides in the library, so someone using it only has to add that one line of code to `startup` or `program` to get it into the service container

Comment: @Brudi_Voeller This works pretty well and I usually provide some overloads as well that will accept some options parameter to setup the configuration like whether you want a singleton,scoped or transient etc. and this keeps everything encapsulated inside the library. I don't know if this is "best" practice but it has worked well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quite common approach is to provide a method, usually in namespace like `MyLyb.Extensions.DependencyInjection` (sometimes even in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` though you should have very specific name in this case) which can be put into a different library, depending on the use case. And then expose the registration:

```cs
namespace MyLyb.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
public static class MyLybRegistrationExtensions
{
    // possibly add another parameter to provide/setup the SDK settings
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyLib(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // registration goes here
        return services;
    }
}
```

Also this method can expose action to set the options for the library - `public static IServiceCollection AddMyLib(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MyLibOptions> setOptions = null)`

For example - [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection)'s integration with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I guess I was on the right track in my own coding, I didn't know that `AutoMapper` followed this same kind of design. +1